# TNS-01153 : Failed to Process the String

Tags: oracle11g

I have installed Oracle 11g in windows 7 , I am connecting Oracle but getting error
TNS-01153 : Failed to Process the String ...

This is my `TNSNAMES.ORA`:

```
work_prod =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =localhost) (PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =(SID =workprod))
  )
```

And my `LISTENER.ORA`:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY =workprod))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =localhost(PORT = 1521))
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = workprod)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\MY_DISK\G\Oracle_database\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = workprod)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\MY_DISK\G\Oracle_database\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

Comment: How are you connecting - what code/command generates the error?

Comment: "lsnrctl start" command . When i execute in cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis in your second `listener.ora` address, after `localhost`:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY =workprod))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =localhost(PORT = 1521))
  )
```

... should be:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY =workprod))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =localhost)(PORT = 1521))
  )
```

Which suggests, along with the formatting, that you're editing this by hand rather than using `netca`.

Your SID list also looks odd; I think that should be:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = PLSExtProc))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\MY_DISK\G\Oracle_database\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = workprod)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\MY_DISK\G\Oracle_database\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = workprod)
    )
  )
```

... assuming your database SID and service name are both `workprod`. But the `DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER` suggests your DB is called XE, which implies you're using Oracle 11g Express Edition, so something still doesn't quite add up. Maybe that line just shouldn't be there, if you've copied it from somewhere else.

I *think* the ORA-28547 might come from connecting over TCP but trying to hand off to `extproc`, mixing protocols; but not entirely sure.

Comment: Thanks Alex , but can you share me how to use netca for generating listener??

Comment: @kartik - actually you might want net manager at this point; [see the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/network.htm#ADMQS042), and follow the link to the Oracle Database Net Services Administrator's Guide to decide which tool to use.

Comment: Thanks..!!Let me check

Comment: Ya it worked , but got another error ORA-28547 :connection to server failed ,probable Oracle net admin error.

Comment: @kartik - I'd be tempted to throw the files away and start from scratch in netca, but  can see something that looks odd so I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for every thing its working fine . But i need to start listner from CMD every time i restart the PC . Any alertnate so that i can avoid restarting.??

Comment: @kartik - I don't know under Windows; I think you can set the [service to auto-start](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e10845/admin.htm#i1005939) but I don't have experience of doing that. This is something else that is probably done for you if you use the config tools instead of creating your own file - Oracle Net Manager might let you set up auto-start. I really don't know though, sorry.

Comment: thats ok. Thanks for everything.